# Analyzing a moderation of a threeway interaction

Tags: regression, interaction

I’m not yet a very experienced researcher nor -analyst, and I would very much appreciate some help with my research project.

I first ran a study where I found a regular two-way interaction Then, I ran a follow-up study where I found a threeway interaction: the nature of the interaction effect from the first study was hypothesized and found to depend on a third variable. My supervisor now wants to run a follow-up to this follow-up, to look for moderators of this threeway interaction effect.
My worries are that the analyses will be messy, and that the study is likely to be underpowered with our budgets.
I’m posting here to see if any of you here know of appropriate analyses that aren’t messy.

I’ll describe my series of studies in vague and simplified terms.

Study 1:
Participants first responded to a personality trait-scale. Then, they read a text and answered questions about it. The contents of the text where manipulated experimentally, between subjects: in one condition, participants scoring highly on the personality-trait were predicted to respond positively, while those with low scores were predicted to be negative. And in the other condition, these two predictions are switched.
Thus, we predicted and found an interaction between the trait and the condition on how participants rated the text:

Rating ~ trait + condition + traitXcondition

Study 2:
The design here is equal to that in study 1, except that participants now all respond to both conditions of the experiment. They respond to the first condition without knowing that the second is coming, and they respond to the second without being able to go back and alter responses to the first.
Order of presentation is randomized as a between subject factor. The prediction was that the order would impact responses, as participants would copy their first responses when answering the second time. The nature of the interaction between the trait and the condition will then depend on whether a response is first or second in the presentation order:

Rating ~ trait + condition + order + traitXcondition + traitXorder + conditionXorder + traitXconditionXorder

Order is dummy-coded as either 0 or 1, depending on whether a response is first or second in the order. A signficant coefficient for traitXcondition replicates the finding from Study 1, and a significant threeway interaction shows that the nature of this effect changes depending on whether a response is preceeded by having first responded to the opposite condition. (I also have random intercepts for each subject, to account for how they all respond two times)

Study 3:
My supervisor suggested that the size of the effects in study 1 and 2 might depend on how participants score on a second personality trait. So she wants to run a study to investigate this.

The problem:
To my mind, the way to do the analysis for Study 3 would be to look for a four-way interaction:

Rating ~ trait1 + condition + order + trait2 + trait1Xcondition + trait1Xorder + trait1Xtrait2 + conditionXorder + conditionXtrait2 + orderXtrait2 + trait1XconditionXorder + trait1XconditionXtrait2 + trait1XorderXtrait2 + conditionXorderXtrait2 + trait1XconditionXorderXtrait2

Which I think is way too messy, and I suspect I would also need a pretty massive sample size to have adequate power.
Am I wrong in thinking these things? Can any of you give me suggestions for how best to do my analysis for Study 3?